# $\sin(x)<\cos(x)$ and $\tan(x)<1$ confusion

Tags: trigonometry

Correct me if I'm wrong but the above inequalities are same right?

But when I solve the first one the solution is
[0 , pi/4) U (5pi/4 , 2pi]

But when i solve other one I get
[0, pi/4) U (pi/2 , 5pi/4) U (3pi/2 , 2pi]

Why?

Comment: They are not the same, they differ by a factor of $\cos x$, and that may be negative.

Comment: Because the inequality $\sin(x)<\cos(x)$ is not equivalent to $\tan(x)<1$ but it's equivalent to $$\begin{cases}\tan(x)<1\\ \cos(x)>0\end{cases}\cup\begin{cases}\tan(x)>1 \\ \cos(x)<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: The same question: is $x<y$ and $\frac{x}{y}<1$ the same?

Answer (score 2):

When you divide by a negative number, you flip the inequality symbol, so when $\cos{x} <0$ (note strict inequality), and you divide through by it, you get $\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} =\tan{x} >1$

The best way to solve the inequality is to sketch the graphs and use points of intersection to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\frac{4\pi}{3}$, then $\sin(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}<-\frac{1}{2}=\cos(x)$, but $\tan(x)=\sqrt{3}>1$, so no, the two inequalities are not the same.

Furthermore, if $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then the first inequality is defined (and false), but the second one is not, and if $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then the first inequality is true, and the second is undefined.

---

The inequalities are only the same if $\cos (x) > 0$.